# How to introduce superscript in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I want the output format date like 14th may 2015. the **th** in 14 it should come with sup tag but sup tag is not accessing here. the output i am getting in ph102 variable. Getsuffix(csq.EventDate.Value.Day) in this only i am getting suffix of th st and rd for date

My code:

```
PdfPTable table9 = new PdfPTable(4);
table9.WidthPercentage = 99;
table9.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
table9.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
Phrase ph101 = new Phrase("Event Date & Time", textFont2);
PdfPCell cellt1 = new PdfPCell(ph101);
cellt1.Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER + PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER + PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER;
cellt1.PaddingTop = 0F;
cellt1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cellt1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
DateTime eventTime = DateTime.Today;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(csq.EventTime)))
    eventTime = DateTime.Today.Add(csq.EventTime.Value);
Phrase ph102;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csq.EventDate.ToString()))
{
    ph102 = new Phrase(csq.EventDate.Value.Day +  Getsuffix(csq.EventDate.Value.Day) + csq.EventDate.Value.ToString("MMM") + " " + csq.EventDate.Value.Year + " at " + eventTime.ToString("hh:mm tt"), textFont7);
}
else
{
    ph102 = new Phrase();
}
PdfPCell cellt2 = new PdfPCell(ph102);
cellt2.Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER + PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER + PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER;
cellt2.PaddingTop = 0F;
cellt2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cellt2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
```

Comment: Have you seen this link http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-convert-html/

Comment: As Bruno said, your question is very confusing. Is your actual question "How do I make superscript text"? Also, when you say "sup tag" and "HTML" are you just using this for comparative purposes and in reality you aren't parsing HTML in any way?

Answer (score 5):

When I read your question, I assume that you want something like this:

[image]

However, you are confusing people as is demonstrated in the comment from somebody who gives you a hint to use HTML to PDF. Your answer is *"no sir it cant work"* which is a strange answer, because it *can* work. It's just not what you meant when you talked about sup tag. At least, that's what I assume when I look at your code, I don't see any HTML.

In your code, you create a `Phrase` like this:

```
 ph102 = new Phrase(csq.EventDate.Value.Day
     +  Getsuffix(csq.EventDate.Value.Day)
     + csq.EventDate.Value.ToString("MMM")
     + " " + csq.EventDate.Value.Year
     + " at " + eventTime.ToString("hh:mm tt"), textFont7);
```

This complete `Phrase` is expressed in `textFont7` which can't work in your case, because you want to use a smaller font for the `"st"`, `"nd"`, `"rd"` or `"th"`.

You need to do something like this (see [OrdinalNumbers](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/OrdinalNumbers) for the full example):

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Font small = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6);
    Chunk st = new Chunk("st", small);
    st.setTextRise(7);
    Chunk nd = new Chunk("nd", small);
    nd.setTextRise(7);
    Chunk rd = new Chunk("rd", small);
    rd.setTextRise(7);
    Chunk th = new Chunk("th", small);
    th.setTextRise(7);
    Paragraph first = new Paragraph();
    first.add("The 1");
    first.add(st);
    first.add(" of May");
    document.add(first);
    Paragraph second = new Paragraph();
    second.add("The 2");
    second.add(nd);
    second.add(" and the 3");
    second.add(rd);
    second.add(" of June");
    document.add(second);
    Paragraph fourth = new Paragraph();
    fourth.add("The 4");
    fourth.add(rd);
    fourth.add(" of July");
    document.add(fourth);
    document.close();
}
```

This is the **Java** code to create the PDF in the screen shot. You'll have to adapt your code so that it works in C#. As you can see, you can not just concatenate your `string`s using the `+` operator. You need to compose your `Phrase` or `Paragraph` using different `Chunk` objects. What you call "sup" is done by using a smaller font and a text rise.